# Video from a different source than youtube into an fancybox

Tags: html, css, video, fancybox

could anybody tell me how could I embed this video to a fancybox popup?
Video: http://www.tm-tube.com/video/28199/XTA+-+WAR+4+-+THC+VS+3DMAX+-+R3

Website: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/index/gallery/0-9
Under: Having Fun! i would like to replace that image with the video from link above.

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, go on TMTube and get the embed code for your video.

Second, use the `Inline content` way described in the [Fancybox doc](http://fancybox.net/howto) :

```
<a class="fancybox" id="inline" href="#video">This shows your video</a>
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="video">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tm-tube.com/js/embed.js.php?id=28199"></script>
         <noscript><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.tm-tube.com/vimp.swf?playlistmode=media&amp;mediaid=28199&amp;webtv=false&amp;hosturl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tm-tube.com%2Fflashcomm.php" id="flashcontent_511cc6b591bcf" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" name="c6a80378-3eb2-47e7-8415-ba1f7cff037e" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="480" height="270" align="middle"><param name="movie" value="http://www.tm-tube.com/vimp.swf?playlistmode=media&amp;mediaid=28199&amp;webtv=false&amp;hosturl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tm-tube.com%2Fflashcomm.php" /><param name="width" value="480" /><param name="height" value="270" /><param name="align" value="middle" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /></object></noscript>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/csZ64/).

Comment: This works perfect, but i wonder, is there possible to bring back the design of fancbox? before it was with semi transparent black background and different positioning.

Comment: it was different from what i had before, anyway i managed to get is back like it was before and with the video fancy working. thank you very much